# Can we create an indexed field which is not unique

Tags: custom-field, externalid, indexing, custom-index

I am extremely new to salesforce. I read that we can mark any custom field as an ExternalID which creates an index over it. I have a use-case where I have multiple Address records which have the same value for the CustomerID field. Is it possible to create an index on CustomerID?

Basically, can ExternalID be non-unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An External Id doesn't have to be unique. You can have a field marked as external id, which will create an index. One caution is that if it isn't unique then you can't use that field for an Upsert.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000325076&type=1

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can I choose which field is being used for the Upsert? I will have another ExternalID which is unique.

Comment: Yes see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm

Comment: Thanks! One last question, can I fetch all records matching a repeating ExternalID? This API shows only one record is returned: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_retrieve_with_externalid.htm

Comment: I'm not sure. It would be best to ask a new question if you can't find the answer on here already. We don't want to bury good information in the comments.

Comment: Done:  https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/363189/fetch-all-records-matching-a-repeating-externalid