# Fetch all records matching a repeating ExternalID

Tags: rest-api, api, externalid

I have a non-unique custom field which is an ExternalID. Is it possible to fetch all records matching a given value using the REST API? The [documentation example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/using_resources_retrieve_with_externalid.htm) shows the API returns one record.

Assume there are never more than 10 records for a given ExternalID value.

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the result? Alternately, you can just perform a SOQL query.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a use case for the [query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_query.htm) endpoint. It allows you to make a SOQL query or SOSL search through the REST API. Example below, adapt the query to use the particular field you have in mind:

```
/services/data/v53.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id+FROM+Account+WHERE+External_Id__c+=+'123'
```

The query string value is the same syntax as a SOQL query but escaped for a URL.

Answer (score -2):

For your use case, you need to create a custom web service class in which you can pass the externalId field value and return the list of records. You can refer to this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm).